# Counting occurrences of elements in a pandas series containing lists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've been working with large lists of data, where each element is a single string, ex:

```
["apple", "egg", "carrot", "milk", "apple", "apple"]
```

I've been turning these into pandas Series and then using value_counts() to count the occurrences of each unique item in the list. However, now I'm facing lists that contain lists:

```
["apple", ["apple", "egg"], "egg", "carrot", ["milk", "egg"], 
 ["milk", "apple", "carrot"], "apple"]
```

I'm looking for a way to count the occurrences of each unique list in addition to each unique string.

I've tried turning these lists of lists into series and using value_counts() on them, but it throws an `unhashable type: list` error. I get the same error when I change these sublists to sets or ndarrays.

I could always throw these lists into a bunch of for loops but I don't know if my computer has the computational power to do that in any reasonable amount of time. I'd love something that works with similar speed to value_counts(), but I can't for the life of me figure out how to implement it. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you encapsulate sub-lists to string as follows

```
Your sample:

In [392]: s
Out[392]:
0                    apple
1             [apple, egg]
2                      egg
3                   carrot
4              [milk, egg]
5    [milk, apple, carrot]
6                    apple
dtype: object


s.astype(str).value_counts()

Out[391]:
apple                          2
egg                            1
carrot                         1
['milk', 'apple', 'carrot']    1
['milk', 'egg']                1
['apple', 'egg']               1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: That's great, and exactly what I wanted! Could you explain a little more of what is happening? Does ```astype(str)``` cast all elements in the series as strings, and then count them as such? What would happen if I had two different lists containing the same elements, but in different orders? (```['milk', 'egg']``` vs. ```['egg', 'milk']```)

Comment: `astype(str)` converts elements of `s` to string. On any sublist such as `['milk', 'egg']`,  it encapsulates the sublist to `"['milk', 'egg']"`. Same elements but different-order strings are considered as 2 different strings, so `['milk', 'egg']` is counted separately from  `['egg', 'milk']`